# Jax-ws client not detected by Websphere 7

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, websphere-7, ws-security

we have a client jax-ws jar generated by a provider.

when i put the jar inside a war (and then the war inside an ear) and i deploy the client in websphere inside RTC, the jar is not detected by the server.

if i login into the console and look for webservice client, i have nothing:

[image]

so i cannot configure the security policy for the client, and when i call the service, i receive the following error

```
 javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: security.wssecurity.WSSContextImpl.s02: com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityException: Exception org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: CWWSS6500E: Il n'existe pas de candidat d'identité d'appelant pouvant être utilisé pour la connexion. ocurred while running action: com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerHandler$1@4f904f9
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1310)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1036)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.java:583)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:529)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:470)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:185)
```

can you help me??